# Tabbed Navigation Anything Slider

Tags: css

I installed the anything slider on my site and I'm trying to get the navigation to be tabbed like this: http://www.echappee-laine.fr/

I updated the CSS to make the tabs but I'm pulling my hair out trying to understand what went wrong because 1) the links don't cover the entire box, and 2) now that I've done this the navigation isn't responsive. (http://beta.harvest-express.com)

Any thoughts?

```
/* Navigation buttons, default state */
.anythingSlider .anythingControls ul a.cur, div.anythingSlider .anythingControls ul a {
    background: #777;
    color: #000;
}

/* Navigation buttons, active state */
.anythingSlider.activeSlider .anythingControls ul a.cur, 
div.anythingSlider.activeSlider .anythingControls ul a {
    background-color: #7C9127;
}

/* Navigation Links */
.anythingSlider .anythingControls { 
    position:absolute; 
    top:0; 
    left:0px; 
    list-style:none; 
    padding:0; 
    margin:0; 
    width:235px; 
    z-index: 20; 
}

.anythingSlider .anythingControls ul {
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    float: left; 
}

.anythingSlider .anythingControls ul li { 
    display: block; 
    height: 75px; 
    width: 235px; 
    border:1px solid #ccc; 
    background-image: url(.../transparant.png);
}

.anythingSlider .anythingControls ul a {
    font: 11px/18px Georgia, Serif;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 2px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 75px;
    background-image: url(../images/default.png);
    background-position: center -288px ;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    text-align: center;
    outline: 0; 
}

.anythingSlider .anythingControls ul a:hover {
    background-image: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1) the links don't cover the entire box

You have `display: inline-block` set on your `a` tags; unless you have a specific reason why they need to be that way, I'd change that to be `display: block` allowing the link to expand to fill up the containing `li`. Alternatively you could add a `width: 100%` to that rule.

> 2) now that I've done this the navigation isn't responsive

You've got an explicit width of 235px set on the `anythingControls` div.

Comment: (*slaps forhead*) that's why I'm a newbie. @ultranaut thanks!